# How to add a recovery email in ejabberd api based

Tags: api, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

While registering a new account, the user needs to provide username and password on API based registration.

How can we add one more field to add user's email while registering new account on API?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that only username and password is required, and possible to set.

Other user details can be set in the user vCard, once the user is registered.
For example, using ejabberdctl to register and later set email in vcard, and getting it:

```
$ ejabberdctl register user1 localhost mypass
$ ejabberdctl set_vcard2 user1 localhost EMAIL USERID micorreo@aa.com
$ ejabberdctl get_vcard2 user1 localhost EMAIL USERID
micorreo@aa.com
```